# ¿Dónde es correcto anidar la etiqueta <nav></nav> para crear un menú en HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

He hecho un ejercicio para clase donde he creado un pequeño menú dentro del body, pero fuera del header que creé para la cabecera de la página y me lo han dado por válido sin mayor problema. Hoy, practicando con freeCodeCamp, he visto que en uno de los ejercicios el menú  estaba incluido dentro del header. Aunque las dos posibilidades me han funcionado en la práctica, ¿qué más correcto?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente [W3C Recommendantion](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-nav-element.html#the-nav-element) **no dice que la etiqueta `<nav>` deba ser colocada dentro o fuera de `header`**.

Por lo que se puede deducir de lo que ellos dicen y de los ejemplos que ponen, el lugar donde debe ir `nav` depende de cómo esté estructurada la página y lo que `nav` represente en ella.

De hecho, ponen dos ejemplos de uso, uno dentro de `header`. Nótese además que aquí hay dos etiquetas `header`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otro fuera de `header`. Nótese además que aquí hay dos grupos de `nav`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es relevante lo que dice W3C Recommendation sobre estos dos casos de uso de `nav`:

#### Primer caso

> In the following example, the page has several places where links are
>   present, but only one of those places is considered a navigation
>   section.

#### Segundo caso:

> In the following example, there are two nav elements, one for primary
>   navigation around the site, and one for secondary navigation around
>   the page itself.

---

Traducción (las negritas son mías):

#### Primer caso

> En el siguiente ejemplo, la página tiene varios lugares donde los
>   enlaces están presentes, pero solo uno de esos lugares se considera
>   una **sección de navegación**.

#### Segundo caso

> En el siguiente ejemplo, hay dos elementos de navegación, uno para la
>   **navegación principal** alrededor del sitio y otro para la **navegación secundaria** alrededor de la página.

Es más W3C Recommendation dice que `nav` sirve hasta para escribir poesías:

> Un elemento de navegación no tiene que contener una lista, también
>   puede contener otros tipos de contenido. En este bloque de navegación,
>   los enlaces se proporcionan en prosa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Conclusión

El lugar donde deba ir `nav` debe decidirse según la forma en que la página esté estructurada y según lo que ese elemento represente en la página.

---

Para profundizar en el tema, recomiendo la lectura del [*Semantic navigation with the nav element*](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/), publicado en `html5doctor.com`

Comment: Hasta donde se nav hace referencia a NAVEGACIÒN y como mencione las etiquetas se crean para que se usen de acuerdo a su necesidad, solo menciono el caso, porque sería mal ver un sitio web con todo en div. Pero cerrando el tema espero que sea de utilidad para la persona que publico la pregunta

Comment: Una respuesta muy útil. Me ha venido bien conocer algunas posibilidades más de la etiqueta nav. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Lara, me alegro de que te haya servido. En el artículo de `html5doctor` que refiero al final de la respuesta advierten (casi al final en el sub-apartado *The difference of nav from menu*) de no confundir un `nav` con un elemento `menu`. Es un caso muy frecuente de confusión, quizá convendría profundizar un poco sobre eso.

Answer (score 5):

Lo ideal es que siempre que inicies un proyecto nuevo lo principal siempre debe estar en una etiqueta HEADER como (titulos, menú de navegación, etc) y dentro de la misma NAV pata tu menú. Los navegadores encuentran y filtran más rápido tu búsqueda de acuerdo a las buenas practicas que se ejecuten en el desarrollo del código.

Esto también lo hace referencia la w3 y MDN (mozilla Developer Network)
HEADER para lo principal de tu sitio web que necesites, y dentro de la misma etiqueta el NAV ya que sigue siendo principal en el sitio web.

luego sigue todo el contenido del sitio que se usa un MAIN para todo el contenido y finaliza con el pie de página que sería el FOOTER.

Te dejo un ejemplo Básico.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Img/Favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- ENCABEZADO -->
    <header class="encabezado">
        <h1>Developer Web</h1>
        <!-- MENÚ DE NAVEGACIÓN -->
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Información</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- TODA LA INFO DEL SITIO -->
    <main class="container">

    </main>


    <!-- PIE DE PÁGINA -->
    <footer class="pie-pagina">

    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Un buen sitio web se caracteriza por usar las etiquetas HTML de una manera correcta y para las cuales fueron creadas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero he revisado la documentación de W3 y MDN antes y después de leer tu comentario y no logro encontrar ninguna recomendación al respecto. ¿Podías enlazarlo si existe esa referencia explícita? A mí también me pareció más lógico al principio incluir mi nav dentro del header, ya que era un menú común -por tanto, estructura de header común- a todos mis documentos html del proyecto, pero supongo que esto dependerá de cada caso.

Comment: Nunca dije que fuera obligatorio el uso de las etiquetas, por eso copie hace "referencia", porque la MDN indica el mejor uso de la etiqueta header y nav, porque cuando un sitio esta correctamente creado y usa las lineas de código correcta es mucho mas sencillo para un navegador posicionarlo en busquedas, filtraciones y mas procesos. Te dejo los enlaces donde yo consulto las información sobre esas dos etiquetas https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/header, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/nav

Answer (score 3):

La forma correcta es la de la izquierda. Porque lo que haces es distinguir un elemento de otro y te ayudara a encontrar facilmente otros elementos dentro del codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Dennis Nuñez la parte correcta es a la izquierda, pero si estás del todo inseguro, usa una herramienta llamada [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) que te ayudará a saber si estás usando la semántica correcta en un documento HTML.